# How can I get only rows that contain a value above the average?

Tags: r

I have a list of dataframes called "mylist", each dataframe has two columns "Date" (class posixct) and "Num_tweets" (class numeric).
For each dataframe in the list I'd like to consider only rows where the "Num_tweets" are above the average of all value on the Num_tweets column.

My code so far:

```
above_average <- lapply(mylist, function(x) x$Num_tweets > mean(x$Num_tweets))
```

The problem with this code is that it returns "FALSE" and "TRUE" instead of selecting the value above the average.

Comment: Try `above_average <- lapply(mylist, function(x) x[x$Num_tweets > mean(x$Num_tweets), ])`

Comment: this should also work: `lapply(mylist, function(x) subset(x, Num_tweets > mean(Num_tweets)))`

Comment: @stefan I think you should you answer it. I couldn't find a good target to dupe it